# DFS with adjacency matrix in c

Tags: c, depth-first-search

I'm trying to write a DFS code with adjacency matrix and stack. The output is okay except one value at the end which I don't know where it came from.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a[100][100], i, j, n;

void dfs(int root)
{
    int vis[10], v, s[10], c, top = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        vis[i] = 0;

    vis[root] = 1;
    top++;
    s[top] = root;

    while (top >= 0) {
        int v = s[top];
        c = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (a[v][i] == 1 && vis[i] == 0) {
                top++;
                s[top] = i;
                vis[i] = 1;
                c = 1;
            }

           if (c == 0)
               top = top - 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d", s[i]);
}

int main()
{
    int root;
    printf("numarul de noduri:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("root node:");
    scanf("%d", &root);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);

    dfs(root);
}
```

Could somebody maybe hint whats wrong ? 
I tried debugging it in c bust still can't tell.

Comment: What is the input? What is the expected output? What is the output, what is the value at the end? Can you please format your code to be more readable?

Comment: Could you use more informative names rather than i,j,c, vis , n, top ? If would make the code more readable.

Comment: `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` probably needs some `{}`. At least, I do.

Comment: regarding: `int vis[10], v, s[10], c, top = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`  if the value in `n` is not 10, then this code will either not completely initialize the array `vis[]` or will set values beyond the end of the array.  Strongly suggest using a `#define` rather than `10` and limiting the number of items initialized as `#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 10`  and `for (i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i++)`  similar considerations exist for other statements in the posted code

Comment: OT: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 1):

The example you've provided implements BFS, not DFS. The problem with your code is stack handling. In particular, you don't erase the visited node while trying to reuse the top of the stack. Also, this makes the solution more complicated that it has to be.

```
if (a[v][i] == 1 && vis[i] == 0) {
    top++; // <-- problem: you step over the current node
    s[top] = i; // so it's not overwritten here
    vis[i] = 1;
    c = 1;
}
```

I suggest you use the `top` as an index of the *next empty slot* and not the last written. This can simplify the code as follows:

```
s[top++] = root;
while (top > 0) {
    int v = s[--top];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (a[v][i] == 1 && vis[i] == 0) {
            s[top++] = i;
            vis[i] = 1;
        }
}
```

You should also make `vis` and `s` larger because your adjacency matrix can hold up to 100 nodes while those arrays - only 10.

Answer (score -1):

It does not look like a DFS algorithm which explores each branch as far as possible https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search, but it may work with undirected graph if you take care of not erasing visited nodes with *s[top]=i*.
As far as I know you should explore the branch of each visited node and after that take care of the others nodes.

Comment: It looks like BFS, DFS is usually made with recursivity.